# Bash Shell find repeated attribute and set related attributes to a similar value

Tags: bash

I have a .csv file which contains few repeated values as follows.

```
a,2
b,3
a,1
c,5
b,2
```

I want to identify the repeated values from the 1st column and add the same 2nd column values for all repeated 1st columns. Expected results is,

```
a,2
b,3
a,2
c,5
b,3
```

Is there a way for me to do that?

I'm new to bash, so the solution will be helpful and will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !($1 in a){a[$1]=$2} {print $1, a[$1]}' file
```

```
a,2
b,3
a,2
c,5
b,3
```

**Learning Awk:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems to be working. Could you provide a short explanation as to what the command is actually doing?

Comment: `a` is an associative array with key as `$1` and value as `$2`. When `$1` is not in `a` then create an entry with key-value pair of `$1-$2` in `a`. Moreover I have provided you 2 useful links for more help on `awk`.